# password validation should accept special character, number, character but not whitespaces

Tags: android, regex, validation

I am trying to validate password field for my application. I make validation to check whether string contain spaces or not but it's not accepting special character like '#' and others.

I need to allow user to enter special character but not allow to use white spaces.
Here is my validation code.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(oldPass);
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(newPass);
        boolean found = matcher.find();
        boolean found1 = matcher1.find();
        if(found || found1)
        {
            DisplayError(Constants.PASSWORD_CANNOT_CONTAIN_SPACES);
        }
```

Please give me any hint or reference.

**update**

```
if (newPass.indexOf(' ') != -1 || oldPass.indexOf(' ') != -1) {
    DisplayError(Constants.PASSWORD_CANNOT_CONTAIN_SPACES);
}
```

Comment: How about this: "[ \\n\\t\\r\\f\\v]"

Comment: Please don't do this. There is no reason to reject someone's password because it has a space in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's too simple to use regular expressions.

```
if (password.indexOf(' ') != -1) {
    // display error
}
```

Comment: This won't match space characters other that whitespaces, like tabs, etc.

Comment: @GOTO0 There's seldom a scope for a user to introduce special characters like new lines, tab etc. when providing passwords. For example, an `<input>` text box in an HTML `<form>`. You press tab you move on to next form element.

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil Please update the question with your current code sample.

Comment: is it problem of encoding? can we need to encode password before sending to server?

Comment: That code block won't care if password has `#` or not. Can you share a bigger code sample to actually understand what the code is doing? What did you mean when you said `Still it's not accepting #`? Who is **it**?

Comment: server not accepting '#' .  I am also encoding this but still i am getting null when i use '#'

Comment: your answer is right but i think my problem is not related to validation. may be related to encoding decoding... sorry